# Camel JMS Proxy Timeout occurred after 20000 millis waiting for reply message

Tags: java, jms, apache-camel

I am using a Camel Proxy which returns a result from another process.

```
public interface DataProcessingInterface {
   public List<ResponseData> processPreview(ClientData criteria, Config config);
}
```

And this is configured link this

```
<camel:proxy
id="processPreviewProxy"
serviceInterface="model.jms.DataProcessingInterface"
serviceUrl="jms:queue:processPreview"/>
```

But sometimes the other process takes a long time to return the results and I am having getting the timeout exception

```
TemporaryQueueReplyManager - Timeout occurred after 20000 millis waiting for reply message with correlationID [Camel-ID-PC01-2661-1367403764103-0-15]. Setting ExchangeTimedOutException on (MessageId: ID-PC01-2661-1367403764103-0-17 on ExchangeId: ID-PC01-2661-1367403764103-0-16) and continue routing.
```

How do I tell Camel to wait till the response is ready. It should take forever if that is how long it takes. The client is managed in a different thread so it the duration it takes will not affect the client.

Also is it possible to re-establish the connection if the TimeoutException is thrown so I can continue to wait?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Forever"? No. You can't wait forever.

A (synchronous) request/reply typically have a time out value set by a reason. If you don't get a reply within a given time, then try again or skip it. In the JMS case, you set both requestTimeout and timeToLive to achieve this. Read [this](http://camel.apache.org/jms#JMS-Abouttimetolive) section. In Camel, you can achieve such things with redelivery and error handlers.

Anyway, if you would set the value to "Forever" (or at least very long, such as multiple hours) - then a server/application restart would still make the request fail.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I think "forever" is "not a good strategy". I will combine a timeout with an ExceptionHandler to retry the request again. Much more smarter than waiting forever. tx

Comment: +1 for "server/application restart would still make the request fail".

Answer (score 1):

You can set a very high request timeout on the jms endpoint.

```
jms:queue:processPreview?requestTimeout=xxxx
```